# List not changed outside the method

Tags: c#

I noticed interesting action, when I change list inside some method, and throw exception inside this method, then out of scope of the method list is not changed.

How to change force this list to be changed in catch block? using out ?

```
List<string> list = null;
try
{
    list = new List<string>{"1", "2", "3"};
    ChangeMyList(list);
}
catch
{
    //here list has 3 elements , why ? 
}

void ChangeMyList(List<string> list)
{
    list = list.Except(new List<string>{"1", "2"}).ToList();
    //here this list has only one element
    throw new Exception();
}
```

Comment: List object was declared in inner scope of try block so it doesn't even exist in block catch

Comment: Your code is not getting compiled. How the code in ChangeMyList method works: List<string>("1", "2")?

Comment: Ive updated your code to actually compile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inside `ChangeMyList`, `list` is a copy of the reference to the source list pointed to by `list` in the outer scope. Assigning to this local reference does not affect the reference in the caller. You can use `ref` to pass `list` by reference:

```
void ChangeMyList(ref List<string> list)
{
    list = list.Except(new List<string>("1", "2")).ToList();
    //here this list has only one element
    throw new Exception();
}
```

then

```
List<string> list = new List<string>{"1", "2", "3"};
ChangeMyList(ref list);
```

Comment: wow, I thought that if you pass by reference like passing List, then if you modify inside, then outside will be also changed, opposite to when you pass by value like int... so how it works ?

Comment: @kosnkov - You pass by reference by using `ref` or `out` which you are not doing in your question. Parameters are passed by value by default, which for reference types means the reference is copied, so you have two references to the same list object. You can mutate the list through both references (e.g. by calling `Add` or `Remove` on the list) but if you want assignments to be visible in the caller you have to pass by reference.

Answer (score 2):

This is not because of the exception; your list is not being changed because the reference to it is copied when you call the function, as in, `list` in your function is a copy of `list` in the parent scope, and any changes to it won't be made to the original one.

You have two solutions:

Either make your function return `list`, and store it back into the original variable:

```
try {
    having List<string> list = new List<string>{"1", "2", "3"};
    list = ChangeMyList(list);
} catch() {
}


List<string> ChangeMyList(List<string> list)
{
    list = list.Except(new List<string>("1", "2"));
    return list;
}
```

Or you can simply pass your list with the `ref` keyword to indicate that the function will modify it:

```
try {
    having List<string> list = new List<string>{"1", "2", "3"};
    ChangeMyList(ref list);
} catch() {
}


void ChangeMyList(ref List<string> list)
{
    list = list.Except(new List<string>("1", "2"));
}
```

Comment: wow, I thought that if you pass by reference like passing List, then if you modify inside, then outside will be also changed, opposite to when you pass by value like int... so how it works ?

Comment: The *list* isn't copied, its the *reference to the list* which is copied - this is a misleading answer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was already given but just for those who, like me, understand it better in a graphical way:

[image]